# Cannot get GraphicsMagick (gm) to compare two files correctly

Tags: graphicsmagick

Trying to use the GraphicsMagick) gm module in node to compare two local .png files and output their difference as a third .png for further analysis later.

Using the sample code from http://aheckmann.github.io/gm/docs.html:

```
var gm = require('gm');

var options = {
  file: '/home/ubuntu/workspace/difference/diff.png',
  highlightColor: 'yellow', // optional. Defaults to red
  // tolerance: 0.00
}

gm.compare("/home/ubuntu/workspace/images/logo.png", "/home/ubuntu/workspace/images/logo2.gif", options , function (err, isEqual, equality, raw) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('The images are equal: %s', isEqual);
  console.log('Actual equality: %d', equality)
  console.log('Raw output was: %j', raw);
});
```

Despite both files being completely different, gm always reports their equality to true unless I pass it a tolerance of 0.00 - whereupon the diff.png that's generated is simply a ywllo tinted (highlighted) version of logo1.png

What I'd hoped was (a) the the code spotted the two files were different and (b) the diff simply highlighted the areas of difference in yellow, rather than tinting the entire image.

Must be something I'm doing wrong, but what?

Answer (score 0):

In your description, you say two png files, but in your code it the second is a .gif.  Is this the source of your problem?  You may be able to get around it by using GraphicsMagick to convert to the same format.